# Read file using delimiter and add to array

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read from a text file that is in my project workspace then;

- Create an object depending on the first element on the first line of the file
- Set some variables within the object
- Then add it to my arrayList

I seem to be reading the file ok but am struggling to create the different objects based off what the first element on each line in the text file is

Text file is like this

```
ul,1,gg,0,33.0
sl,2,hh,0,44.0
```

My expected result is to create an `UltimateLanding` object or `StrongLanding` object based on the first element in the text above file example

***Disclaimer - I know the `.equals` is not correct to use in the IF statement, i've tried many ways to resolve this***

My Code -

***Edited*** -
*It seems the program is now reading the file and correctly and adding to the array. However, it is only doing this for the first line in the file? There should be 2 objects created as there are 2 lines in the text file.*

```
     Scanner myFile = new Scanner(fr);
     String line;
     myFile.useDelimiter(",");
while (myFile.hasNext()) {
    line = myFile.next();
    if (line.equals("sl")) {
        StrongLanding sl = new StrongLanding();
        sl.setLandingId(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        sl.setLandingDesc(myFile.next());
        sl.setNumLandings(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        sl.setCost(Double.parseDouble(myFile.next()));
        landings.add(sl);
    } else if (line.equals("ul")) {
        UltimateLanding ul = new UltimateLanding();
        ul.setLandingId(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        ul.setLandingDesc(myFile.next());
        ul.setNumLandings(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        ul.setCost(Double.parseDouble(myFile.next()));
        landings.add(ul);
    }
}
```

TIA

Comment: `myFile.equals("sl")` compares your `Scanner` object with a `String`. You would actually want to compare your read string `line`, not your `Scanner` object. So `line.equals("sl")`. Note however: `nextLine()` will read **the whole line**. So `line` will never be equal to "sl". Use `line = myFile.next()` to read the next token up to the specified delimiter.

Comment: In addition to @maloomeister you need this code inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your current code.

- `myFile.equals("sl")` compares your `Scanner` object with a `String`. You would actually want to compare your read string `line`, not your `Scanner` object. So `line.equals("sl")`.
- `nextLine()` will read **the whole line**. So `line` will never be equal to "sl". You should split the line using your specified delimiter, then use the split parts to build your object. This way, you will not have to worry about newline in combination with `next()`.
- Currently, your evaluation of the read input is outside of the `while` loop, so you will read all the content of the file, but only evaluate the last line (currently). You should move the evaluation of the input and creation of your landing objects inside the while loop.

All suggestions implemented:

```java
...
Scanner myFile = new Scanner(fr); 
// no need to specify a delimiter, since you want to read line by line
String line;
String[] splitLine;
while (myFile.hasNextLine()) {
    line = myFile.nextLine();
    splitLine = line.split(","); // split the line by ","
    if (splitLine[0].equals("sl")) {
        StrongLanding sl = new StrongLanding();
        sl.setLandingId(Integer.parseInt(splitLine[1]));
        sl.setLandingDesc(splitLine[2]);
        sl.setNumLandings(Integer.parseInt(splitLine[3]));
        sl.setCost(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[4]));
        landings.add(sl);
    } else if (splitLine[0].equals("ul")) {
        UltimateLanding ul = new UltimateLanding();
        ul.setLandingId(Integer.parseInt(splitLine[1]));
        ul.setLandingDesc(splitLine[2]);
        ul.setNumLandings(Integer.parseInt(splitLine[3]));
        ul.setCost(Double.parseDouble(splitLine[4]));
        landings.add(ul);
    }
}
...
```

However, if you don't want to read the contents line by line (due to whatever requirement you have), you can keep reading it via `next()`, but you have to specify the delimiter correctly:

```java
...
Scanner myFile = new Scanner(fr);
String line; // variable naming could be improved, since it's not the line
myFile.useDelimiter(",|\\n"); // comma and newline as delimiters
while (myFile.hasNext()) {
    line = myFile.next();
    if (line.equals("sl")) {
        StrongLanding sl = new StrongLanding();
        sl.setLandingId(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        sl.setLandingDesc(myFile.next());
        sl.setNumLandings(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        sl.setCost(Double.parseDouble(myFile.next()));
        landings.add(sl);
    } else if (line.equals("ul")) {
        UltimateLanding ul = new UltimateLanding();
        ul.setLandingId(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        ul.setLandingDesc(myFile.next());
        ul.setNumLandings(Integer.parseInt(myFile.next()));
        ul.setCost(Double.parseDouble(myFile.next()));
        landings.add(ul);
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @maloomeister

It seems the program is now reading the file and correctly and adding to the array. However, it is only doing this for the first line in the file? There should be 2 objects created as there are 2 lines in the text file

Comment: Thanks @maloomeister, looks good! I'm working through some examples and one of the challenges is to see if you can achieve this without using a second array. I note your splitLine[] is a string array. Would you have any quick suggestions around this?

Comment: @JakeStillone I added the alternative solution with the workaround back. The trick is to add the newline to the set of used delimiters for the scanner.

Answer (score 0):

A solution.

```
List<Landing> landings = Files.lines(Paths.get("LandingsData.txt")).map(line -> {
        String[] split = line.split(",");
        if (split[0].equals("sl")) {
            StrongLanding sl = new StrongLanding();
            sl.setLandingId(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
            sl.setLandingDesc(split[2]);
            sl.setNumLandings(split[3]);
            sl.setCost(Double.parseDouble(split[4]));
            return sl;
        } else if (split[0].equals("ul")) {
            UltimateLanding ul = new UltimateLanding();
            ul.setLandingId(Integer.parseInt(split[1]));
            ul.setLandingDesc(split[2]);
            ul.setNumLandings(split[3]);
            ul.setCost(Double.parseDouble(split[4]));
            return ul;
        }
        return null;
    }).filter(t -> t!= null).collect(Collectors.toList());
```